# odd datatables behavior when there are no results. 1 works, 1 doesn't

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am seeing this odd thing happen - i'm using datatables to grab dynamic data but the issue that i am having is that one table is applying the 'dataTables_empty' class to the results, the other is not. Any ideas? Screen shots below. Both tables are configured the exact same way in the code.[image]
[image]

Code:

```
  function searchOrdersHandler(data) {
    if (!ax.Utils.dataSurety(data)) {
      return false;
    }
    if (!ax.theUser.permissions['orders|view']) {
      return false;
    }

    var theData = ax.Orders.addUniqueProductString(data.data.results);

    ax.Utils.buildBreadcrumbs($searchBreadcrumbs, [{
      link: window.location.hash,
      text: "Search"
    }, {
      link: window.location.hash,
      text: data.data.search_label
    }], '&gt;');

    if (!orderGlobalSearchDTO) {
      orderGlobalSearchDTO = $searchOrdersTable.DataTable({
        destroy: true,
        data: theData,
        columns: ordersSearchMap,
        autoWidth: false,
        paging: false,
        dom: 'ft',
        searching: false
      });
    } else {
      orderGlobalSearchDTO.clear();
      orderGlobalSearchDTO.rows.add(theData);
      orderGlobalSearchDTO.draw();
    }

    ax.Tables.responsify($searchOrdersTable);
    SearchPVM.globalOrdersLoading(false);

  }; //searchOrdersHandler
```

Comment: Please describe what do you do when `dataTables_empty` doesn't get applied. Is `searchOrdersHandler()` being called()? Could it be that your data `theData` contains `No data available in table` message?

Comment: Hi - yes, it's in the orders function where the class doesn't get applied. The same function more or less is used for "Search Businesses" but the class gets applied there ( in the screen shot). Thank you.

Comment: Was just wondering if anyone had any ideas here. Thanks